# Execute multiple update statement in dynamic query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014. I want to update one column, then after this column use in second update statement in dynamically generated query.

My query looks like this:

```
declare @squery varchar(max)
set @squery =   'if('+CHAR(39)+@AppendType+CHAR(39)+' = ''Address'')
begin
    update tblchild set name=(REPLACE(LEFT(phone,2)+LEFT(a,1),' ',''))
    update a  set a.a=a.name,a.name = b.name,a.email= b.email,a.b = '1' from tblchild as a , tblmaster as b where a.phone = b.phone
    update a  set a.name = b.name,a.phone = b.phone,a.a=b.a,a.b = '1' from tblchild as a , tblmaster as b where a.email = b.email and (a.b IS NULL or a.b = '')
end'

print(@squery)  
exec (@squery)

select * from tblchild
```

but this is not working.

My table looks like this:

```
name    email          phone            a   b
----------------------------------------------
s       z@a.in          111            NULL 1
u       a@ghf.ij        222            NULL 1
x       qww             333            NULL 1
ik      k@gmail.com     1234567890     NULL 1
kinjal  kin@abc.com     7894561230     NULL 1
```

Answer (score 1):

the single quotes inside a string must be "doubled". It should look like this:

```
declare @squery nvarchar(max)
declare @AppendType nvarchar(max) = N'Address'

set @squery =   N'if('+CHAR(39)+@AppendType+CHAR(39)+N' = ''Address'')
begin
    update tblchild set name=(REPLACE(LEFT(phone,2)+LEFT(ISNULL(a,''''),1),'' '',''''))
    update a  set a.a=a.name,a.name = b.name,a.email= b.email,a.b = ''1'' from tblchild as a , tblmaster as b where a.phone = b.phone
    update a  set a.name = b.name,a.phone = b.phone,a.a=b.a,a.b = ''1'' from tblchild as a , tblmaster as b where a.email = b.email and (a.b IS NULL or a.b = '''')
end'

print(@squery)  
execute sp_executesql @squery

select * from tblchild
```

Comment: can you please provide sample data for tblchild and tblmaster? to which table belong the sample data in your question?

Comment: this data is for tblChild

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!!!

I create key from `phone` and `a` column and than update. But my column `a` is null so it's can't merge.

use

```
update tblchild set name=(REPLACE(LEFT(phone,2)+LEFT(ISNULL(a,''''),1),'' '',''''))
```

instead of

```
update tblchild set name=(REPLACE(LEFT(phone,2)+LEFT(a,1),' ',''))
```

Comment: ok so there was a data-driven problem too - didn't see that but i edited my answer